# git: detached head after 'git reset --hard bd53134

Tags: git, reset

I'm working in a branch and needed to undo a couple of commits. So I did

```
$> git reset --hard bd53134
```

This had the desired effect, except that I have now a detached head :(

```
$> git status
HEAD detached at bd53134
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you may still be poking around with this, so here's a bit of background.  You mentioned in a comment that you started a `git rebase` and were stuck with `git rebase --continue` always complaining.  (This really should have been part of the original question.)

First a note: `HEAD` can be normal ("not detached"?) or "detached".  A "normal" `HEAD` consists of nothing but a branch name.  If you're "on branch `master`", `HEAD` just says "on branch master".  A "detached HEAD", which sounds like something from the French Revolution, consists instead of a raw SHA-1 commit-ID.  I like to write attached HEADs, in the drawings below, as `HEAD=branch`, and then show where the branch points, using an arrow to point to one particular commit.

Before you start a rebase, you have a commit graph that might look something like this:

```
...- A - B - E - F         <-- master, origin/master
           \
             C - D         <-- HEAD=branch
```

In this case, I've assumed that you did a `git checkout -b branch` from `master`, and made a few commits on `branch` (creating `C` and `D`), and then maybe did a `git checkout master` and `git pull` which brought over commits `E` and `F` from "remote `origin`".  Then you went back to `branch` with `git checkout branch` (hence `HEAD=branch`).

You then decide that you should re-base both `C` and `D` on top of `F`, giving the more linear commit sequence:

```
...- A - B - E - F         <-- master, origin/master
                  \
                   C' - D' <-- HEAD=branch
```

(I'll show in a moment why those are `C'` and `D'` instead of `C` and `D`.)  So you run `git rebase master` to "move" commits `C` and `D` onto the tip of `master`.

Rebase does not actually move commits.  What it does is *copy* some *existing* commits, making new ones that "do the same thing" and are "just as good" (we hope!).  So, rebase keeps `C` and `D` around.  It uses a special label, `ORIG_HEAD`, to keep track of commit `D` (and a bunch of additional `.git/rebase-apply/` files to track all progress throughout the rebase operation—these files are in fact how git knows that the rebase is "in progress").

Rebase starts the process by adding this `ORIG_HEAD` and "detaching HEAD".  It sets the "detached HEAD" to point *directly* to the target of the rebase (commit `F`, in this case).  (By poking around, it seems the documentation lies slightly about it resetting the branch, too.  But this may differ in older versions of git; I think the docs were accurate at one point.)  Thus:

```
...- A - B - E - F         <-- master, origin/master
          \       \
           \       \...... HEAD [detached]
            \
             C - D         <-- ORIG_HEAD, branch
```

Then, for each commit (`C` and `D` here), it gets the changes made in the commit, and tries to apply those same changes to the `HEAD` commit.  If all goes well—it usually does—it makes a new commit with the same message as the old commit.  That's commit `C'`:

```
...- A - B - E - F         <-- master, origin/master
          \       \
           \       C'..... HEAD [detached]
            \
             C - D         <-- ORIG_HEAD, branch
```

After successfully applying `C` to `F` to make `C'` coming off `F`, the rebase command goes on to attempt to apply `D` to the new (but still detached) `HEAD`, `C'`.  However, this time something goes wrong: the patch does not apply:

```
CONFLICT ...
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at ...
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
    ...

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

At this point, your commit graph looks like the (somewhat messy) graph I drew above.

As rebase prints, you can:

- resolve the problem manually and `git rebase --continue`, or
- choose to drop a commit (`D`, in this case) with `git rebase --skip`, or
- back out of the whole thing with `git rebase --abort`.

Choosing the last option tells rebase to stop the rebase attempt, put `HEAD` back the way it was, and delete the "rebase in progress" status/tracking files.  This also drops the entire chain of new (but not yet labeled with a branch) commits.  (Technically, they are still in there, in the reflog.  You just won't see them, normally.)

Doing the first ("resolve manually"), or choosing the middle ("skip") option, lets rebase continue onward.  Let's say you resolve the problem and `git rebase --continue`.  Once rebase runs out of commits—and `D` is the last one—it moves the branch name to the final commit, and sets `HEAD` to the branch name again.  So in this case, you get this:

```
...- A - B - E - F         <-- master, origin/master
          \       \
           \       C' - D' <-- HEAD=branch
            \
             C - D         <-- ORIG_HEAD
```

Since commits pointed-to by `ORIG_HEAD` are not normally shown, it looks like `C` and `D` are gone, and the copies (`C'` and `D'`) are the only commits left.  (As always though, `C` and `D` are actually still in there, and will stick around for a while, until the reflog entries expire.)

---

With all that in mind, once you're in "detached HEAD" state, `git reset --hard` has no branch name to affect.  It will move `HEAD`, and change the working directory, but `HEAD` will still point directly to a commit.  So any `git reset`s you do in the middle of a rebase are, well, weird at best.  (They'll fiddle with what happens with the rebase if you continue it, as continuing a rebase just keeps adding on to wherever `HEAD` points at the time.)

In the more normal case (when you're "on a branch"), `HEAD` has the name of the branch.  Then (and only then), `git reset` can and does change the commit the branch-name points-to.

How do you tell which actions `git reset` will take, and what's going on?  The answer is to **use `git status`**.  If you're not sure what's going on, `git status` is meant to help.  It's gotten much better in the last few years at actually helping, too! :-)

Comment: Fantastic answer. git answers are much better when they have this kind of background explanation rather than a quick answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you are on a branch, `git reset --hard bd53134` is supposed to update the branch, and leave you on that branch. Because of that, I suspect you weren't actually on a branch.

If that is correct, one way to fix it by going back to the branch:

```
git checkout <branch>
```

and then run the same `git reset` command again that you already used.

Comment: That might be true. Before the reset I tried to rebase. The problem I had was that after every 'git rebase --continue' it showed the same file with conflicts. Could this be the problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately, if I checkout the branch again, it is missing some commits, so I guess I didn't push all the commits before rebasing :( Is there any way to to tell git that my current status is the HEAD ?

Comment: When you're in the middle of a rebase, `HEAD` is always detached.  Use `git rebase --abort` to terminate the rebase operation, leaving the original branch unchanged (git will put `HEAD` back at the tip of the not-rebased-after-all branch).

Comment: Your current status is always HEAD. You jave probably commited when was deattached. You can use git reflog to find your missing commits. Checkout the branch you want to work on and cherry pick them there (or reset the branch pointer there)

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Suppose you've got commits A, B, C, D, E. Your HEAD (what you thought was your branch) is E. Your branch actually is A. Your branch should be B. `git checkout <branch>` would lose B, but `git reset --hard B` would then bring it back. `bd53134` is your B, as I understand it.

Comment: Then again, torek's comment is also a good point. Even if you manually fix up your branch, git will still think a rebase is in progress unless you explicitly abort it.

Comment: The weird thing is that I did an abort, but that didn't fix it. Are there more situation except a rebase for a detached head ?